# i am trying to make this carousel to be moving towards the left on its own, anybody with help, am new here

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/
jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
<div id="carousel">
//with in this div i made list of my images
</div>
<a id="navPrev" href="#">Next</a> <a id="navNext" href="#">Previous</a></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
//Define the animation speed for the Carousel
var speed = 600;
$('#navPrev').click(function(){
//As the rest of our carousel is hidden, lets move it's margin left until
//it's in view
//We use the jQuery animate() function give this movement a nice smooth feel
$('#carousel ul').animate({marginLeft:'-280px'}, speed);
});
$('#navNext').click(function(){
//And now lets move back to the start of the Carousel
$('#carousel ul').animate({marginLeft:'1px'}, speed);
});});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's best for you if you just follow a tutorial instead of trying to do things by yourself, as plenty will come that you did not think about it yet, and all the links above already did.

> [28 Useful JQuery Sliders You Need To Download](http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/28-useful-jquery-sliders-you-need-to-download/)
>
> [13 Super Useful jQuery Content Slider Scripts and Tutorials](http://webdesignledger.com/tutorials/13-super-useful-jquery-content-slider-scripts-and-tutorials)

Comment: thanks alot thats the reason why am here to get real time help and guide.

Comment: for real time you can use the Chat, or IRC :)